# pip: failed to create process

Tags: python, windows, pip

Apologies, I know this question has been asked a bunch, but none of those solutions seem to work for me.
Windows 10
Python 3.7.7
C:\Python7 is my directory
PATH variables are set
python -m ensure pip states requirements satisfied
There are no .py scripts in the scripts folder to add a line to, only .exe files

I'm so lost

Comment: It is not entirely clear what your issue is, but if you can start pip with `python -m pip` but not `pip` then it may be that you need to add `C:\Python37\Scripts` to PATH as perhaps only `C:\Python37` was added

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, pip wont work, it gives me the error in the title. However the reverse of your idea worked! I had the scripts folder in PATH, not the main Python folder, adding it just now worked.

Answer (score 0):

Both C:\Python7 and C:\Python7\Scripts needed to be in path apparently, I only had the Scripts one.